# Get information about socket of unknown domain

Tags: linux, socket, netstat, lsof

The output of lsof (revision: 4.87) on centos 7.8.2003 shows:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
java    30858 xxxx  841u     sock                0,7       0t0 561359758 protocol: TCPv6
java    30858 xxxx  876u     sock                0,7       0t0 561093427 protocol: TCPv6
```

How do I learn more about those sockets?

Comment: note: I would tag this `ss` instead of netstat, but do not have the privilege.  If anyone would like to add that tag, please do so.

Comment: But there's nothing about netstat or ss in this question!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sure there is: I'm trying to get statistics about a socket, so `ss` (ought to be) completely appropriate.